# How do I make many ChartJS charts on the same page to have the same height and also even column width?

Tags: angular, chart.js

I made the question for myself so I can share you what I found.

The problem is that if you have multiple charts on the same page and want them to look more or less the same while having different number of columns, then you will end up with different column width when using vertical barcharts.

Comment: Please edit the question in such way to clearly present problem you are solving. That usually includes [mcve] that shows problem.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was, add [ngStyle] to the DOM element.

```
<canvas [ngStyle]="canvasStyle" baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [options]="barChartOptions" [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
      [legend]="barChartLegend" [labels]="barChartLabels" [chartType]="barChartType">
    </canvas>
```

Then from typescript I set the height and width:

```
private setChartHeight(): void {
    const width = this.factorData.length * 5;
    this.canvasStyle = {
        height: '30vh',
        width: `${width}vw`,
    };
}
```

It is important though, that you set the `maintainAspectRatio: false` attribute so that you can set both the height and width. Of course if that's your desire. If you only want to set the chart width you can set it to true.